# Sum different values from same column

Tags: sql, sum

I need to sum all the temperatures for all stations by hour:

```
station       hour     temperature
-----------------------------------
100             1          2
101             1          2
100             2          4
101             2          4
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
hour     temperature
---------------------
1            4
2            8
```

... where the temperature for station 100 gets added to station 101 (2 + 2 = 4) and so on.

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest that you read about sql aggregrate functions. There are many similar problems like this that can be solved by them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this:

```
select hour,sum(temperature)
from MyTable
group by hour
```

Comment: Well that was easy! Thanks for that.

My question is a very simplified version of a problem i had to solve at work - which I solved today but with a lot more code than this! On Monday I will try this very simple solution and see if it works.

The database I am working on has 270 stations and 8736 hours and I have to find the average temperature for all the stations for each hour.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
select hour,sum(temperature) from table_name group by hour;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use GROUP BY.

```
SELECT hour, SUM(temperature) FROM myTable GROUP BY hour
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select hour,SUM(temperature) FROM Table GROUP BY hour
```

Comment: Isn't distinct redundant if you group by hour?